# PHP SQL - JSON - Message List

Tags: php, sql, sorting

I am working on a educational project to create a simplified messaging system for an IOS app.  and am having problems sorting my Message List (Not the actual Conversation List)

Table: Messages - FIELDS = id, touser, from user, date, message, photo, readmessage.
Current Code :

```
 <?php
 $enduser = $_GET['username'];
 $db = b2fdev;
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","admin","admin");
 if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
 mysql_select_db($db, $con);
    $arr = array();
   //Execute the query
        $rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE touser = '$enduser' GROUP BY fromuser");
        while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
        $arr[] = $obj;
         }
        echo '{"users":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
 mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

the coming results show.....

{"users":[{"id":"359","touser":"knitsu","fromuser":"skye","date":"2013-07-04 07:07:44","message":"miss you","photo":"","readmessage":"NO"},{"id":"327","touser":"knitsu","fromuser":"tota","date":"2013-04-08 05:49:46","message":"not much just chilling ","photo":"","readmessage":"NO"}]}

which is fine, except one thing, the messages it is showing, is the first ones in the table, which are not the most recent messages,  how would i sort it to show the most recent message ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your query to the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM messages a
LEFT JOIN messages b
    ON a.fromuser = b.fromuser
    AND a.date < b.date
WHERE b.date is null
AND a.touser = '$enduser' 
ORDER BY LOWER(a.fromuser)
```

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/29/5ht.png/  is a link of the table

 shouldn't that mean that id # 382 and 359 displayed, if the user is knitsu ? 


just to clarify, the message list, only shows the most recent message from a user who have messaged the user that is logged in?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking. The message ids which were sent to knitsu are 327, 359, 381 and 382. I have know idea if knitsu was logged in or not.

Comment: so basically when I run that script, a few things happen

it finds messages for  user signed in say "knitsu"  it finds all messages, in that table, and then groups them by from user, so the final table only shows one message from each user, so the message list shows only one message from a user to knits, however that message it is showing is not the most recent message

IE:  the message from tota, was the oldest message, and not the newest message, and sorting by date, did not do anything

 sorry if that doesn't make sense

Comment: I just saw your message, and I updated my answer. If you need to send a message, use the `@` followed by my user name (type "p" and click on the name that pops up), otherwise I don't get notified.